# jQuery asp control .prop(“disabled”, “”) not enabling check box in IE 9

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I’m trying to enable a check box on an Aspx page using the following code.

```
$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_chkCheque1").prop("disabled", "");
```

This code is executed when an item in a drop down list is clicked and works in chrome and Firefox, but not IE 9.

I can see the code being run in the script debugger but it doesn’t affect the check box control.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

for sureshot result make use of `true` and `false` with `jquery` try this.

```
$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_chkCheque1").prop("disabled",false);
```

Comment: I preferred your answer when you only recommended `prop` :-\

Answer (score -5):

Please try:

```
$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_chkCheque1").removeProp("disabled");

or

$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_chkCheque1").removeAttr("disabled");
```